# Why sinatra won't load if 'require sinatra' is in another file?

Tags: ruby, require

I have web.rb file that works fine. I wanted to move all require files in one requires.rb file and call this file from all my .rb files and use conditions based on a caller file name to require what is needed.

I tested it on **'require pp'**, **'ruby-growl'** and and it worked fine. But sinatra won't load if the `require sinatra` is in another file.

Can I have `require sinatra` in a different file? Or better in general can I have require in different file?

using

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
- sinatra (1.3.2)
- gem 1.3.7
- running the scripts from dos window by `ruby script_name.rb`

Few first lines from my requires.rb are below. When I run web.rb I can see the text "loading web requires". Note that I require 'rubygems' for all .rb files. If I comment `require 'sinatra' I get an error message 'web.rb:17: uninitialized constant Rack (NameError)'. If the require is not commented ruby finishes without any message on the screen, no error message either.

```
called_from=caller[0].split(":")[0]
puts "loading web 'requires' for file: #{called_from} ..." if (["web"].any?{|s| called_from[s]})

require "c:\\edutester\\others\\settings.rb"

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'           if (["web"].any?{|s| called_from[s]})
```

## UPDATE

I simplified the test case. I have two files. If I use only test.rb and require in the file. Everything works fine. If I use test_require.rb file I can see "loading" text and I'd say that something is loading or something is processin because it takes a second or so to finish the test.rb

test.rb

```
#require "c:\\edutester\\playground\\test_require.rb"

require 'rubygems' 
require 'sinatra'


get '/' do

    "yes"
end
```

and test_require.rb

```
puts "loading..."
require 'rubygems' 
require 'sinatra'
```

---

Sinatra won't load = I don't get the usual

```
== Sinatra/1.3.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin 
>> Thin web server (v1.2.7 codename No Hup) 
>> Maximum connections set to 1024 
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

and I cannot access the web server from a browser. And there is no message at all. Hm, there is one empty line

Comment: Requiring from another file should be fine.  Do you `require rubygems` first?

Comment: Yes, I do 'require rubygems' for all .rb files. I updated my question with more info.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "sinatra won't load"?  I had assumed you meant the require failed with an error message.

Comment: Sinatra won't load = I don't get the usual `== Sinatra/1.3.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.2.7 codename No Hup)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop` and I cannot access the web server from a browser. And there is no message at all. Hm, there is one empty line ...

Comment: Consider using Bundler instead of manually requiring things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run a Sinatra program directly with something like `ruby my_app.rb`, Sinatra can start a web server automatically. Sinatra [determines whether to run this built-in server by checking whether the `:run` setting is `true`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__enabledisable_the_builtin_web_server).

The default for value `:run` is determined by checking if the `:app_file` setting is the same as the Ruby file being executed, i.e. `$0`.

Sinatra [determines the default value for `:app_file` by using the first file that executes `require 'sinatra'`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L6-L9). In this case, when you have `require 'sinatra'` at the top of `test.rb` then `:app_file` is `$0`, so Sinatra starts the built-in server. When you use `test_require.rb`, `$0` is `test.rb`, but the file to require Sinatra, and therfore `:app_file`, is `test_require.rb`, and as they don’t match the built-in server isn’t started.

To fix this you can explicitly set `:app_file` in your `test.rb` (or `web.rb` or wherever):

```ruby
set :app_file, __FILE__
```

You’ll need to do this *after* you’ve required Sinatra. You could also directly set `:run`, although this would be less flexible as it would run the built-in server every time, which you  wouldn’t want if you’re using `config.ru` for example:

```ruby
enable :run
```

Although this should solve your problem, personally I think it would be better to keep the `require 'sinatra'` together with the Sinatra code.